# Kendo Listview template using Angular ng-show to display and hide object

Tags: angularjs, listview, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I am working with a Kendo Listview to show charts.  I would like for the user to have the ability to click a check box to show or display individual charts.  Currently I am trying to use ng-show but can not get it to work.

My template in my listview options

```
template: <div #:chartData.kendoDirective# k-options="vm.#:chartData.chartOptions#" ng-show="#:visible#" class="move k-block" id="#:chartData.htmlID#" style="float: left; margin: 5px 0;"></div>'
```

visible is a parameter coming back in my response from the server to tell me whether to initially show or hide this item.  I would then like to have the check box change the visible variable to show or hide the chart.  Below is a screen shot showing the box.

[image]

UPDATE:  I have gotten the initial items to work using the following

```
ng-show="this.dataItem.visible == true"
```

However I still can not get the chart to show/hide based on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by updating the listview datasource each time a checkbox was clicked.  So when I one of the checkboxes was clicked I made the following call.

```
        $("#selectedchart_listview").data("kendoListView").dataSource.data(vm.selectedView.charts);
        $("#selectedchart_listview").data("kendoListView").refresh();
```